# Comparable without implementing

Tags: java

I'm new to java. I'm learning Interfaces and I'm trying to do the following:

```
package comparator;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class comparator {
    public static bankAccount ba=new bankAccount(80);
    public static void main(String args[]){
    method1(ba);
    }
    public static void method1(bankAccount ba1){
        bankAccount ba2=new bankAccount(80);
        int c=((Comparable) ba1).compareTo(ba2);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
class bankAccount{
    public double balance;
    public A(double bal){
        balance=bal;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: comparator.bankAccount cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at comparator.comparator.method1(comparator.java:25)
    at comparator.comparator.main(comparator.java:20)
```

I'm unable to understand this new type of error. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I'm unable to understand why you are trying to cast things to `Comparable` that aren't `Comparable.` What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @user1658435 check the post with example!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply can't cast an object of `bankAccount` type to `Comparable`. You need to implement the `Comparable` interface in your `bankAccount` class and override the `compareTo()` method.

```
public class bankAccount implements Comparable {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Your logic goes here
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Where have you defined the class bankAccount? (side-note: in Java classes are typically UpperCamelCase. So that ought to be BankAccount).

In order to cast a bankAccount object to Comparable, the bankAccount class must implement the Comparable interface. i.e.

```
public class BankAccount implements Comparable {
...
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
    ...
    }
}
```

By implementing Comparable, you also must define a compareTo(Object o) method.

Answer (score 1):

Your `bankAccount` `class` needs to implement `Comparable` interface.

```
class bankAccount implements Comparable{
   public int compareTo(Object obj){
    .......
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to cast it to a Comparable, it needs to implement Comparable, and you need to have a compareTo function.

Change the class declaration to

```
public static class Comparator implements Comparable<Comparator> {
```

and also make sure to implement a compareTo function so that it knows how to compare two of them!

Answer (score 1):

Either you need to implement the interface [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) on your object to compare what you want;  or you can write a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), instantiate and call it, passing both objects you want to compare.  Or compare two fields of the object which are some type such as `String` which already implements comparable.

Answer (score 0):

> Consider Following Example with implementation to use Compare Method I
>   have created a BankAccount Pojo with propertiest AccountNo and
>   AccountName , it can b any property in your case.. and in my case
>   accountNo is unique as well.

```
  public class BankAccount implements Comparable {
    int accoutnNo;
    String accountName;

    public String getAccountName() {
        return accountName;
    }
    public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
    }
    public int getAccoutnNo() {
        return accoutnNo;
    }
    public void setAccoutnNo(int accoutnNo) {
        this.accoutnNo = accoutnNo;
    }
    public int compareTo(Object bAccount) {
        int thisAccount = ((BankAccount) bAccount).getAccoutnNo();
        //      ascending order
        return this.accoutnNo - thisAccount;
        //      descending order
        //return thisAccount -this.accoutnNo ;
    }
}
```

Now you can use **Comparable in Main Method**

Answer (score 0):

Did you implemented Comparable interface in

```
public class bankAccount implements Comparable {
```

you are using compareTo method on bankAccount but it is not finding it.
Implement Comparable, code should be fine.